# C# - Leer datos de un archivo .txt y mostrarlos en un combo box

Tags: c#

Necesito leer datos de uns archivo .txt, el cual tiene n lineas, pero solo requiero leer la primera y cada 8 lineas a partir de esas.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora, solo que este muestra todo lo escrito en el txt.

```
public partial class frmCARGAR_MODELO : Form
{
    public frmCARGAR_MODELO()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string line;
        int counter = 0;
        //string[] datos;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();
   }
```

Estos son los datos que veo hasta este momento en el combo box, como comente, solo debemos ver el primer dato y cada 9, el primer caso seria ver el 62009 y despues 656, etc.

```
62009
PIEZA
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
1
656
PIEZA
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
4
123
PIEZA
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo hacerlo con un foreach

```
      int counter = 0;
      //se recorrera el archivo por cada fila
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt"))
        {
            //Si el contador es 0 estamos en la primer posicion la cual se agrega
            if (counter == 0)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
            else if (counter == 9)
            {
                //si el contador es la posicion 9 entonces agregamos.
                comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                //Regresamos el counter a 0 para empezar el conteo
                counter = 0;
            }
            //incrementamos aquie el contador para que el if ==0 solo entre una vez
            counter++;
        }
```

si quieres mantener el while, yo lo pondria asi:

```
 string line;
            string[] datos;

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Si el contador es 0 estamos en la primer posicion la cual se agrega
                if (counter == 0)
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                else if (counter == 9)
                {
                    //si el contador es la posicion 9 entonces agregamos.
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    //Regresamos el counter a 0 para empezar el conteo
                    counter = 0;
                }
                counter++;
            }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, funciono a la perfeccion.